# Xcode error: "This Apple ID cannot be used for development with Xcode"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I wanted to test my app on my iPhone and this bug occurred. I haven't enrolled Apple Paid Developer Program, but iPhone testing worked for me before.

What should I do?

I appreciate your help with my problem.

Comment: Not enough info, but a few questions come to mind. (1) How *long* ago did your iPhone work? (2) Is it the *same* iPhone? (3) What version of Xcode? (4) Again, same version? (5 & 6) Project? Same two questions. (7) Finally, is the project/Xcode/iPhone combination that "worked for you before" still work? Best I can do to help you without more details. Pretty sure it's the same for everyone else too. (Other than telling you to enroll your Apple ID.)

Comment: 1. About 8 months 2. Yes it is still iPhone 6s 3. Xcode 9.4.1 4. No, I updated Xcode, about 5 and 6 can you be more specific, 7. Yes it does

Comment: @dfd Do you think that to solve this problem I will need to enroll Paid Apple Developer Program

Comment: I honestly don't know. This Apple ID that cannot be used for development... have you logged into ADC with it today? If I remember correctly, the *only* thing you can do *with* the paid program - that you cannot with any Apple ID - is upload to App Store Connect. See if (1) you can login to ADC and (2) see your registered device.

Comment: I logged in on Apple Developer website, but on welcome page I see nothing. It is just a blank white page.

Comment: I just tried, and logged in and on the home page saw my name and *"Apple Developer Program"*. Maybe you have some issue with the ID.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that some Apple iOS features (like Apple Pay) can be used in development only in Valid Apple Development Program. Maybe you are using on of those? Source: https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/ (section Advanced Capabilities)

Comment: Actually no, I am not using any special Apple Features. And I don’t have any issues with my Apple ID

Comment: What's strange is that i logged onto my different Apple ID account and it worked just fine.